# Rank-1 random matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, positive-definite, random-matrices

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with continuous coordinates such that $\|X\|_2=1$ a.s. Define the random matrix $A=XX^T$. It is obvious that $A$ has rank 1 and its unique non-zero eigenvalue is 1. Therefore, $A$ is **not** positive definite since it has $n-1$ eigenvalues equal to zero.

On the other hand, for any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v\neq 0$, we have that $Y_v:=v^TAv=v^TXX^Tv=(v^TX)^2$, and $Y$ has to be a continuous random variable since $X$ has continuous coordinates. Therefore, $P(Y_v=0)=0$ and $P(Y_v>0)=1$, and this happens for any non-zero $v$. This is saying that $A$ **is** positive definite with probability one!!

What is wrong with this reasoning? Any help will be appreciated.

(I think the problem is with $P(Y_v>0)\neq P(Y_v>0\text{ for all }v)$. )

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but $(v^\top X)^2$ can equal zero, no?

Comment: @JST99 If $X$ were fixed, yes, it can. But $X$ is a random vector with continuous coordinates, so $(v^TX)^2=0$ is an event that occurs with probability 0 for any $v\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive Definite can be defined as $v^TAv >0 $ for all $v\neq 0$. So as you mentioned, to find the probability of $XX^T$ being positive definite we need to calculate $P(v^TXX^Tv >0 \text{  for all  } v\neq 0)$. This probability is zero. So $XX^T$ is almost surely not positive definite.

If we fix $v$ then compute $P(v^TXX^Tv>0)$ we will find that the probability is $1$. This however, is not the probability we are interested in.

Comment: I understand why $P(Y_v>0\text{ for all }v\neq 0)=0$ by definition of positive definitness. Maybe is a dumb question, but is there a way to show it directly without using that definition? For example, maybe $(Y_v>0\text{ for all }v\neq 0)\subset F$ where $F$ is an event such that $P(F)=0$.

Comment: @RLC Perhaps a more direct method would involve thinking about the probabilities of the eigenvalues being positive, or the kernel of $XX^T$ being only the zero vector.